# Avoid 'uninitialized' errors on injected fields when using the Checker Framework

Tags: java, dependency-injection, checker-framework

The [Checker Framework's Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker) generates an error when it encounters an uninitialised field.

```
[ERROR] /home/glts/src/example/src/main/java/BookRepositoryImpl.java:[39,7]
error: [initialization.fields.uninitialized] the constructor does not initialize fields: em
```

Now, it is a common pattern to have some fields injected via dependency injection:

```
@Repository
public class BookRepositoryImpl implements BookRepository {
    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Book findById(int id) {
        return em.find(Book.class, id);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here, the `@javax.persistence.PersistenceContext` annotation ensures that `em` will hold a reference to an `EntityManager` instance after the repository has been constructed.

More generally, in these cases the application framework guarantees that fields are initialised and non-null when they are used – but the Checker Framework can't know this.

So far, I've found that one remedy is to convert field injection to constructor injection (`@Inject`). This isn't an option in the above example, though.

Is there a way to tell the Checker Framework that a field is injected, and therefore properly initialised and non-null, without simply suppressing these errors?

Comment: Anything you do to tell the Checker Framework that the field is properly initialized will be suppressing the error, so there isn't really a distinction between the two.  I think your question is either, "Can I suppress the error per-field instead of writing `@SuppressWarnings("initialization.fields.uninitialized")` on the whole class?", or "Can I make the Nullness Checker recognize `@PersistanceContext` as that per-field warning suppression without writing `@SuppressWarnings` explicitly?"  Can you please clarify?

Comment: @mernst I see. Then I'm interested in answers to both of your questions. Note that `@PersistenceContext` is part of the Java Persistence API, so I will not be able to change its definition easily.

Comment: In your case the persistence framework might always return a non-null value, but is that a guarantee?  Is it possible for an application to persist a null value into the persistence framework?

Comment: @mernst I'm not sure I understand the question. I trust the dependency injection framework (think Spring, Guice, CDI, JPA, ...) to do the wiring: injected fields may not be null. My goal is to express this trust in a way the Checker Framework understands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can suppress the error for a single field by writing `@SuppressWarnings("initialization.field.uninitialized")` on the field declaration.
2. You can suppress the error for all fields by writing `@SuppressWarnings("initialization.field.uninitialized")` on the class.

There exist injection frameworks that can inject null as a value where a `@PersistenceContext` annotation exists, such as when the .xml file isn't present, the code isn't running in a transaction, etc.  Writing the
`@SuppressWarnings("initialization.field.uninitialized")` annotation is your way of saying that you trust that the one you are using will always inject a non-null value for your code.